# geschafft or geschaffen? which one is past participle of schaffen?

Tags: verb, past-participle

Accordding to Langenscheidt, Oxford, Duden the verb has two past participles, but those have not mentioned when we shall use each one! because the meanings are also the same.

Comment: Depends on context.

Comment: you mean depends on meaning in each context? just like what he has answered here?

Comment: Yes exactly. I voted to undelete the answer.

Comment: For some reason @TheAwfulLanguage deletes a lot of their own answers. Since they deleted it themself, I wouldn't vote on undeleting.

Comment: Another example is *"schleifen"*, which means *1. "to drag sth. along"* and *2. "to cut (a gemstone)"*. The past participle would be *"geschleift"* and *"geschliffen"* respsectively.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"schaffen" has three meanings:

1. to get something managed,
2. to create, to produce something
3. to work (in some regions colloquial or dialect)

"geschafft" is the past participle ("schaffte" is simple past) of the 1st and 3rd

"geschaffen" is the past participle ("schuf" is simple past) of the 2nd

(Side note: "schöpfen" means to create in sense of God or artists. But note this word also has the completely different meaning to laddle!)

Comment: Amazing text/vote ratio :) Couldn't have put it better.

Comment: In Switzerland, AFAIK, _schaffen_ is also used in the sense of  "to work" (i.e., to have a job); though I wouldn't know what participle they use for that...

Comment: That's meaning is not limited to Switzerland. We use it in Northern Germany, too. *Ich muss schaffen gehen.* – *Ich muss zur Arbeit gehen.*

Comment: Consider also the different simple past forms: (1) schaffte (2) schuf

Comment: Good points! I'll add it as a 3rd meaning in my answer above.